# what is the difference between Declared Values and Specified Values?

Tags: css

The difference between [Declared Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#declared) and [Specified Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified)
confused me .

at first I thought the **Declared Values** written by author

and then it filter out to one value **"winning value"** this winning value becomes the [Cascaded Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascaded)

but latter the spec defining **Specified Values**

*The specified value is the value of a given property that the style sheet authors intended for that element.*

so this make me rethink about Declared Values is it the default value for element ? if yes it should be one default value as I know but it looks there are multiples values and cascading rules applied to get one value  **"winning value"**.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a simple example will help. Suppose we have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My demo</title>
<style>
  #foo { color:orange }
  .content { color:red }
  div { color:blue }
</style>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

then there are three rules.

```
#foo { color:orange }
```

does not apply to our div because it does not have the id "foo". `orange` is not a declared value for the color property of our div.

```
.content { color:red }
```

applies to our div because it has class "content". `red` is a declared value for the color property of our div.

```
div { color:blue }
```

also applies to our div because it is a div element. `blue` is also a declared value for the color property of our div.

Now the cascade is applied. The origin and importance of both the declared value declarations are the same so specificity is used to choose between two. The rule `.content { color:red }` has the higher specificity so it provides the "winning" value.

`red` is therefore the specified value for the color property of our div.

Comment: as I get understand you the `winning value` should be equal  `specified value`  but if you take a look in the [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#stages-examples) they provided there are some cases they don't

Comment: @AymanMorsy Indeed. Not part of the example I give, but the [defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#defaulting) process is applied to the winning value, or if there are no declared values, to get the specified value. That affects the winning values "initial" and "inherit", and the "none" case.